# Faster alternative to deparse()

Tags: r

I maintain a package that relies on repeated calls to `deparse(control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger"))`. `control` is always the same, and the expression varies. `deparse()` seems to spend a lot of time repeatedly interpreting the same set of options with `.deparseOpts()`.

```
microbenchmark::microbenchmark(
    a = deparse(identity, control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger")),
    b = .deparseOpts(c("keepNA", "keepInteger"))
)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr min  lq  mean median  uq  max neval
#    a 7.2 7.4 8.020    7.5 7.6 55.1   100
#    b 3.0 3.2 3.387    3.4 3.5  6.0   100
```

On some systems, redundant `.deparseOpts()` calls actually take up the majority of the runtime of `deparse()` ([flame graph here](https://user-images.githubusercontent.com/1580860/70091470-2aa1d180-15ea-11ea-9445-8258048474ca.png)).

I would really like to just call `.deparseOpts()` once and then supply the numeric code to `deparse()`, but that appears impossible without calling `.Internal()` or invoking the C code directly, neither of which is optimal from a package development perspective.

```
deparse
# function (expr, width.cutoff = 60L, backtick = mode(expr) %in% 
#     c("call", "expression", "(", "function"), 
#     control = c("keepNA", "keepInteger", "niceNames", 
#         "showAttributes"), nlines = -1L) 
# .Internal(deparse(expr, width.cutoff, backtick, .deparseOpts(control), 
#     nlines))
# <bytecode: 0x0000000006ac27b8>
# <environment: namespace:base>
```

Is there a convenient workaround?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**1)** Define a function which generates a copy of deparse whose environment has been reset to find an altered version of .deparseOpts which has been set to be equal to the identity function.  In `Run` we then run that function to create a `deparse2` and execute that. This avoids running `.Internal` directly.

```
make_deparse <- function() {
  .deparseOpts <- identity
  environment(deparse) <- environment()
  deparse
}

Run <- function() {
  deparse2 <- make_deparse()
  deparse2(identity, control = 65)
}

# test
Run()
```

**2)** Another way to do this is to define a constructor function which creates an environment in which to put a modified copy of `deparse` and add a trace to that copy redefining `.deparseOpts` as the identity function.  Then return that environment. We then have some function which uses it and for this example we create a function `Run` to demonstrate it and then just execute `Run`.  This avoids having to use `.Internal`

```
make_deparse_env <- function() {
  e <- environment()
  deparse <- deparse
  suppressMessages(
    trace("deparse", quote(.deparseOpts <- identity), print = FALSE, where = e)
  )
  e
}

Run <- function() {
  e <- make_deparse_env()
  e$deparse(identity, control = 65)
}

# test
Run()
```

**3)** A third approach is to redefine `deparse` by adding a new argument which sets `.deparseOpts` to have a default of `identity` and sets the `control` to have a default of 65.

```
make_deparse65 <- function() {
  deparse2 <- function (expr, width.cutoff = 60L, backtick = mode(expr) %in% 
    c("call", "expression", "(", "function"), 
    control = 65, nlines = -1L, .deparseOpts = identity) {}
  body(deparse2) <- body(deparse)
  deparse2
}

Run <- function() {
  deparse65 <- make_deparse65()
  deparse65(identity)
}

# test
Run()
```

Comment: Wow, that's so clever!!! I never would have thought of that! Really looking forward to benchmarking it on all my systems!

Comment: When I apply (1) and precompute the `backtick` argument, deparsing is 6x faster! I'm going with that. Thanks so much for the workaround!

Comment: Hmm..., apparently, `R CMD check` detects the `.Internal()` call in functions produced by (1). Pretty easy to work around, I just need `make_deparse()(expr, control = 64, backtick = TRUE)`. It is silly to reconstruct the deparser every time I use it, but it is still much faster than the naive `deparse()` I was using before.

Comment: Not for me. I tried creating a package with just the `make_deparse` and `Run` functions in (1) and ran `R CMD build` and `R CMD check --as-cran` under `"R version 3.6.1 Patched (2019-11-18 r77437)"`and it did not complain and I didn't need any workarounds.  Are you sure you are not doing something different or in addition that is causing this?

Comment: I guess it could depend on the platform and version. In [this commit](https://github.com/ropensci/drake/commit/f19efcb53aafd9da1fd30f1a1540f4d74c752a25), I saw warnings [here](https://ci.appveyor.com/project/wlandau/drake/builds/29338201#L1516) and [here](https://travis-ci.org/ropensci/drake/builds/621134632#L3496-L3503).

Comment: It was caused by your code defining it at the top level: `direct_deparse <- make_direct_deparse()` .  The code shown in the answer was careful not to do that and only defined it within a function, i.e. within `Run`.